# Attention scores for padded tokens in variable input sequence length

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, attention-model

When using RNNs (LSTM/GRU), we pass input sequence length to restrict unrolling of sequence. So, for examples if actual sequence length is 8 and padded with 2 extra tokens, hidden state of 8th token is copied to 9th and 10th token.

How is attention score computed on padded sequence lengths? Doesn't 8th, 9th and 10th token contribute equally?